# How to set the default amount of rows in datatables plugin?

Tags: datatables

Does anyone know the [Yet Another DataTables Column Filter (yadcf)](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html) js plugin ?
It doesn't have much documentation and I can't figure out how to set the default number of rows to display (it shows 10 rows as default and I want at least 50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: `"pageLength": 50` (for 1.10+) or `"iDisplayLength": 50` (for 1.9-)

Long one:

You need to distinguish between the [datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin and [yadcf](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/) plugin

The sole purpose of yadcf it to allow the user the ability to easily add various types of filters to the datatables table

> This jQuery plug-in allows the user to easily add filter components to table columns, the plug-in works on top of the DataTables jQuery plug-in.

So your current question is not related to the yadcf plugin,

But if you look at the yadcf showcase you can spot that in on of its pages it demonstrate the use of the `iDisplayLength` attribute (which is the one you need your case)

Look at the page Yet Another [DataTables Column Filter - DOM source example](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html), scroll till you see the code snippet used on that page , notice the: `"iDisplayLength": 25`

---

p.s I'm the author of [yadcf](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf)